# How to fix CollectionView cell's size and make an auto layout regardless of the initial state of the Simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

The code to set the width and height of the collectionView's cell is as following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/6, height: collectionView.frame.width/5)
}
```

When the Simulator is vertical before running the scheme, then we get
[image]
and
[image]

But when the Simulator is horizontal before running the scheme, we get
[image]
and
[image]

The size of cells will change as the Simulator's initial state. I think the reason is that `collectionView.frame.width` depends on the Simulator's state.

How to fix the cell's size using auto layout like the code before regardless the ipad's initial state?

Comment: I do not know why this question is downvoted. This question really confused me for two  whole days. It is really hard for a green hand. If you have a better solution, it is better to answer it, not downvote it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let standardWidth = max(collectionView.frame.width, collectionView.frame.height)
    return CGSize(width: standardWidth/5, height: standardWidth/5)
}
```

This simple solution works well.

Comment: @Shaik Riyaz, min or max are all work for me. My key is to fix the size of cells. But the frame.width and frame.height all depend on the state of Simulator's state.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way to get through this is to make it a sqaure rather than a Rectangle . basically have the same value to width/height in my opinion . If it doesnt help you try to below and one small change to your code is to use the bounds instead of the frames .

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width/5, height: collectionView.bounds.width/5)
}
```

also if you could guess a size margin in betweens you could also reduce that  `bounds.width/5 -10`

Comment: It will get the same bug as I said in the question.